# Dynamodb pagination of 10 results

Tags: amazon-web-services, pagination, amazon-dynamodb

I have a message table which I would like to get the last 10 messages for that user and if they click more it would retrieve another 10 until there were no more message left. I could not see how to do this, so far I am able to get message based on time, but this is not exactly what I want. Reading through the documentation I can see it a method called `LastEvaluatedKey`, but where and how do I use this I can't find a working example of this. This is my code for time:

```java
long startDateMilli = (new Date()).getTime() - (15L*24L*60L*60L*1000L);
long endDateMilli = (new Date()).getTime() - (5L*24L*60L*60L*1000L);
java.text.SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String startDate = df.format(startDateMilli);
String endDate = df.format(endDateMilli);


QuerySpec spec = new QuerySpec()
        .withProjectionExpression("to,fr,sta,cr")
        .withKeyConditionExpression("to = :v_to and cr between :v_start_dt and :v_end_dt")
        .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
                .withString(":v_id", username)
                .withString(":v_start_dt", startDate)
                .withString(":v_end_dt", endDate));

ItemCollection<QueryOutcome> items = table.query(spec);

System.out.println("\nfindRepliesPostedWithinTimePeriod results:");
Iterator<Item> iterator = items.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(iterator.next().toJSONPretty());
}
```

How can I modify this to eliminate the time based pagination and use instead a last 10 messages type of pagination?

Comment: Can you query using a descending index (on timestamp?) and limit the number of items per page by using withMaxPageSize(10)? Example at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html.

Comment: @jarmod OH! I have a range index on the 'cr' attribute. How though if a user first gets the 10 (1 page) items, do I send a parameter with to the user which contains which page they are at right now? SO the user would then send me a 0 for the next request which I would increment to one, set pageNum = 1 (Is this the correct variable to increment) and then it would return all of those?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of a way to request page N with the Page<Item, QueryOutcome> iterator approach.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, but I am looking for a user to be able to load more data (Facebook/Instagram like) after they scroll down to the bottom of the application. I need to be able to know where the user is in the application and what new data they exactly need now.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Isn't it the case that scrolling down beyond the last shown item is implicitly a request for the next page (as opposed to a specific page number)? Store the current page (from the pages collection) in the client's session and then increment it when the web page scrolls. No need to iterate backwards or to a specific page at any point, but maybe I'm oversimplifying things.